# Is there a way to detect unmapped json properties when @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) is set?

Tags: json, rest, spring-boot, jackson

I need to detect which json fields are not mapped to the data model after PUT or POST requests.
For example:
If I post this:

```
{
 "firstName": "test",
 "lastName": "test 2",
 "age": 25
}
```

and my model only have firstName and lastName, I want to list all unmapped fields, which in this example is "age" field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is possible using Jackson's annotation `@JsonAnySetter`

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class DTO {
    private String first;
    private String last;
    private Map<String, Object> unknown = new HashMap<>();

    // getters/setters omitted

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void set(String name, Object value) {
        unknown.put(name, value);
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getUnknown() {
        return unknown;
    }
}
```

Simple test:

```
@Test
public void testUnknown() throws Exception {
    String json = "{\"first\":\"John\", \"last\":\"Doe\", \"age\":\"29\"}";
    DTO dto = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, DTO.class);
    assertEquals(1, dto.getUnknown().size());
    assertEquals("29", dto.getUnknown().get("age"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's just about learning which properties are unmapped you may want to consider using this library: https://github.com/whiskeysierra/jackson-module-unknown-property
It logs unmapped properties for all mapped classes without a need to modify class itself.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for even though Nikolay's answer did the job.